# flutter импорт данных из другого файла .dart

Tags: android, flutter

Новичок во flutter. Надо импортировать данные из другого файла дарт. У меня есть Класс:

```
class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {static final List<LatLng> _points = [
LatLng(44.421, 10.404),
LatLng(45.683, 10.839),
LatLng(45.246, 5.783),  ];
```

И вот таких координат у меня тысяча. Я создал файл **coord.dart** с этими координатами. Но мне сайчас их надо вставить в

```
class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {static final List<LatLng> _points = [
сюда  ];
```

Чтобы не засорять главный файл **main.dart**.

Answer (score 0):

В файле **coord.dart** должно быть что-то вроде такого

```dart
  class Coord {
     static final List<LatLng> points = [
       ... (твои объекты координат)
     ];
   }
```

Затем в **_MapPageState** добавь импорт файла coord

```dart
import 'путь к папке/coord.dart';
```

После этого можно обращаться кпеременной **points** в **_MapPageState**

```dart
class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   print(Coord.points);
 }

}
```

Теперь при запуске этого экрана у тебя в консоли будет список инстансов твоих объектов.

Если тебе нужна какие-то 'фейковые' данные для тестирования кода, то можешь обратить внимание на библиотеку [faker](https://pub.dev/packages/faker)